# Polar and Spherical Coordinates Conversion

Tags: calculus

I learnt $dxdy = rdrd\theta$ from Calculus, but why the following doesn't work as expected?

\begin{align}
dx \, dy &= (d[r \cos\theta])(d[r \sin\theta])\\
&= ((dr)\cos\theta-r \sin\theta d\theta)((dr) \sin\theta+r \cos\theta d\theta)\\
&= (\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)r \, dr \, d\theta\\
&=(\cos2\theta)r \,  dr \, d\theta
\end{align}

Comment: How did you move from the 2nd line to the 3rd line?  There should be a $drdr$ term somewhere, and a $d\theta d\theta$ term somewhere.

Comment: The transformation between coordinate systems involves a determinant (the "Jacobian"), $$ dx \ dy \ = \ \left| \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & -r \ \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & r \ \cos \theta \end{array} \right| \ dr \ d\theta \ \ . $$  So your "partial derivatives" are correct, but that one factor should be $ \ (\cos^2 \theta \ + \ \sin^2 \theta) \ $ .